# error when giving mysql as the database (engine) in Django

Tags: django, mysql-connector

In my web application which is being made in Django (`Django==3.2`), I am trying to use `mysql` as the Database, but in the `settings.py`, when I tried to give mysql as the engine :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'USER': DB_HOST,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASS
    }
}
```

and then tried `ruserver` command, I got the following error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.backends.mysql'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/social_network/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 128, in load_backend
    ) from e_user
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.mysql' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

do you know how I can give mysql as the engine in the settings.py? I tried the following but got the same error:

```
mysql.connector.django
```

Comment: [Even a whole stack trace might not be enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310004/11107541) to be a [mre]. I don't know this technology well, so I'd like to confirm: Is this enough information to allow readers to fully reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to install : (mysqlclient)  pip install mysqlclient  in order to use MYSQL as the backend for Django apps ; you will need the mysqlclient library and in your settings.py file do this :

```
#settings.py 

DATABASES = {

'default' : {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'mydatabase',
        'USER' : 'myUser', 
        'PASSWORD' : 'My_passowrd', 
        'HOST' : 'localhost', 
        'PORT' : '' , 
      
        }
}
```

i hope it helped you

Comment: I used the same thing. the code is updated. with that code I got the same error!!! I am wondering if there is any update in Django!

Comment: how about mysqlclient library ? do you have it on venv

Comment: yes I also tried to install mysqlclient library , but got the same error. is there any update in Django?